# How to build a GTK3 application with msys2?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, msys2

I had installed msys2 and mingw-gcc, gtk3 package.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtk3
```

Then I tried to build a test code.

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk\gtk.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, msys2!");
    return 0;
}
```

but this test code wasn't build with error.

```
main.c:2:21: fatal error: gtk\gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

I checked gtk.h's location and fixed and rebuilded.

```
// #include <gtk\gtk.h> -> #include <gtk-3.0\gtk\gtk.h>
C:/msys32/mingw32/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
```

I guess there is my mistake i dont know.

Comment: I have the same problem :-(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go [gtk3 tutorial site](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).

and read  gcc option.

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-0 example-0.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: Download "pkg-config", now where should I put the files you bring? Because when I use this instruction the terminal devuleve me: "no sush directory"

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning (compiling with MSYS2) I have the same problem and procedure as suggested using the following command (or something like that):

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` hello.c -o hello `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

However the error message remained... So after some internet research I discovery that I have to type (in my case) the following command:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw32/lib/pkgconfig
```

or

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig
```

And them use the compile command previously quoted and then things start to running better and I was able to compile and run my programs.

The sad thing (one of many) is that I have to do this procedure every time I restart the MSYS2. I'm taking suggestions for not have to do it anymore :-)

And the other sad thing is in the fact that after reinstall a new version of MSYS2 (and Codeblocks in my computer)  I still able to compile programs, however they are not running due an error with the zlib1.dll.

The message is

```
"The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in 
the dynamic link library zlib1.dll"
```

Comment: I remembered run this command to check where's the packages were stored:

Comment: find / -name *.pc