# Install GTK in windows bug

Tags: c, gtk

I installed GTK for windows (see instructions [here](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows)) but when I try to build this:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I get the following error :

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:10: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory   30 | #include <gdk/gdk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I build my code with:

```sh
gcc main.c
```

Is there something that I am missing?

---

Note : Any good Gtk tutorial suggestion would also be welcomed.

Comment: gcc doesn't know where to find the gtk headers, you'll need to use the [`-I` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) to tell gcc where it can find the gtk header files. Based on your `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, I'm guessing `-I C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0` will do it.

Comment: thanks you . but each time that i add the following folder he asks me another ...

Comment: Did you try using `pkg-config`, like documented [here](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/compiling.html)?

Comment: Bobmorane the link is for Unix system. I'm  on windows

Comment: Seems to work anyway, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266331/how-to-build-a-gtk3-application-with-msys2). Note that I have never done this myself on Windows, but I think it is pretty similar.