# Problem with seting up gtk for c language

Tags: c, user-interface, compilation, gtk

I want to learn gtk to make GUI using c language I installed all the stuff required as per the website installation guide but then I don't know what to do next how to compile the code, I use atom for writing my c code sometimes also dev c++, so can I set up gtk in atom or dev c++ and compile my code and if not is there any good alternatives for compiling gtk code?

Comment: Also note that you can [use the command line to build](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/compiling.html). I personally use this method and Makefiles, which frees me on using a particular dev environment. I can switch editor any time I want.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 what command i need to write in comand prompt to compile a file ? i have already installed MYSY and gtk 3.0 packages are in it.

Comment: I don't have your setup, so I don't know. However, there are such questions already on SO. For example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266331/how-to-build-a-gtk3-application-with-msys2).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dev-C++ (that project is ancient BTW, I would suggest moving on from that) I expect you are working in a Windows environment? I would suggest using MSYS2 for compiling GTK applications in Windows:

https://www.msys2.org/

MSYS uses the Pacman package manager for its shell. You will need to download the following package in order to compile GTK applications in MSYS/MinGW:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```

You should also download gcc and pkg-config to compile:

```
pacman -S pkg-config gcc
```

Note that pkg-config is generally used to compile GTK applications due to the number of dependencies that are required (Glib, Cairo, etc.). I can't imagine you possibly compiling a GTK application using Dev-C++ as a result. You should add the following line to your .bashrc file (this will be located in the home directory of MSYS):

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

A typical compile line for a GTK application would look like this:

```
gcc -o <program> <program>.c $(pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs) -rdynamic -lm
```